# Can Spring's @Scheduled annotation be used with a custom config provider?

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I would like to use the cron syntax feature of Spring's @Scheduled annotation. However, I need to load the cron schedule from a configuration provider other than Spring's PropertyPlaceholder. Is it possible to use a custom provider of properties that the Scheduler can make use of?

Comment: https://analyzejava.wordpress.com/2015/01/16/loading-configuration-properties-from-database-in-spring-based-application/

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a shot